# JS DOM - Difference between document.getElementById & selecting by name

Tags: javascript, dom

I have code like this:

```
<form name="selectForm">
    <select multiple name="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="button" value="Select Cars" onclick="alert('You selected ' + howMany(document.selectForm.cars) + ' cars')" />
</form>
```

My main question is about this line: `document.selectForm.cars`

what does this do and where can I find relevant information to read up on it? Why is it not using the usual `getElementBy...`? [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) only gives interfaces that are not relevant to this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Just did. Did you not understand what I wrote?

Comment: `document.selectForm` is a not-very-good way of referring to the `form` element with the `name` attribute of `selectForm`. `document.selectForm.cars` is the  `<select>` element inside it named `cars`. This old style of using `document.*name*` to refer to elements on the page should be replaced by `document.getElementsByName` or (after giving the `form` an ID) `document.getElementById` in modern code. You could have figured this out by going to the console and typing `document.selectForm`, and you would have seen the `<form>` element displayed.

Comment: I know that and I said that I knew that in my post above. I am looking for documentation on this exact matter for detailed information on how it works.

Comment: Unless you want the question to be closed, you should rewrite the title to be something like "What does document.selectForm mean here?`, and remove the discussion about tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to see this pattern in more recent tutorials because it is a bit archaic:

```
document.selectForm
```

refers to to the `form` element with the `name` (or possibly `id`) attribute of `selectForm`. `document.selectForm.cars` is the `<select>` element inside it named `cars`. This old style of using `document.*name*` to refer to elements on the page should be replaced by `document.getElementsByName` or (after giving the form an ID) `document.getElementById` in modern code.

You could have figured this out by going to the console and typing `document.selectForm`, and you would have seen the  element displayed